# Largest element of matrix with unit determinant

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I noticed that a positive integer $2\times2$ matrix having unit determinant appears to have only single one largest element. I could not find any counter examples so I would be thankful if someone could explain why is this the case or give a counter example. Consider the following:

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
3 & 2 \\
1 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
5 & 2 \\
2 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
10 & 3 \\
3 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is true.

Consider the matrix
$$
\begin{bmatrix}
a & b \\
c & d \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
Its determinant is $ad-bc$.

Case 1. $a=b$ (the case $a=c$ is similar)

In this case we have that $ad-ac=1$ or $a(d-c)=1$. For positive integers it is possible only if $a=1, c=1, d=2$. And here is the maximum element.

Case 2. $a=d$

In this case we have that $a^2-bc=1$.

$b$ can't equal $c$, because there are no solutions to $a^2-b^2=1$.
Thus, $b>a$ (or $c>a$). Otherwise, there are no solutions to $a^2-bc=1$.